# Connect to a database running in a docker container via a local mysql client i.e. workbench

Tags: docker, mysql, docker-compose

I have a mysql database running in a docker container

```
docker ps
6496a209cb30   mysql:5.7.22           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   0.0.0.0:3317->3306/tcp, :::3317->3306/tcp    db
```

I'm able to login to this container via a shell and run queries fine

```
docker exec -it db bash
```

Why am I unable to connect to the same container via a mysql client on my local machine (using mysql workbench)?

[image]

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` config;

```
 #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3317:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
```

For the `Hostname` field - I've tried `127.0.0.1` & `db`;- the name of the running container with no success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your MySQL client is forcing an SSL connection, more specifically TLS 1.2 or higher.

A quick solution to this is to turn off SSL from your mysql workbench.

[image: mysql workbench turn off SSL]

This will not force SSL/TLS and you will be able to connect to the database

Comment: So simple, thanks